# How to reuse results from subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and I am using postgres to run my sql. I have a problem with reusing sub-queries.

Here is the subquery I currently have.

```
    SELECT country.name, city.name, country.continent
    FROM country
    INNER JOIN city
    ON country.code = city.countrycode
    ORDER BY city.population DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

I am outputting 2 different tables and I am inner joining city and country based off of their code. I order them by highest population to lowest and taking only the top 10. 
Result from this subquery is shown as:

```
            name        |       name       |   continent   
    --------------------+------------------+---------------
     India              | Mumbai (Bombay)  | Asia
     South Korea        | Seoul            | Asia
     Brazil             | São Paulo        | South America
     China              | Shanghai         | Asia
     Indonesia          | Jakarta          | Asia
     Pakistan           | Karachi          | Asia
     Turkey             | Istanbul         | Asia
     Mexico             | Ciudad de México | North America
     Russian Federation | Moscow           | Europe
     United States      | New York         | North America
```

Problem is now that how can I reuse such results and figure out which city is also the capital of the country.

So my expected output after reusing the results above is:

```
         name      |   name    |   continent   
    ---------------+-----------+---------------
     South Korea   | Seoul     | Asia
     Brazil        | São Paulo | South America
     China         | Shanghai  | Asia
     Turkey        | Istanbul  | Asia
     United States | New York  | North America
```

In order to achieve my expected output I think I will need to use this line:

```
    WHERE city.name = city.district
```

I have checked out clauses such as WITH but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: is there any column which contain capital name ?

Comment: Yes, it's under city and it's named as district, so city.district

Comment: You have to `declare` as a variable and `set` it for later use

Comment: @PrathapG is there an example I can follow for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try below way

```
with t1 as
(
SELECT country.name as country_name, city.name as cityname, country.continent
    FROM country
    INNER JOIN city
    ON country.code = city.countrycode
    ORDER BY city.population DESC
    LIMIT 10;
) select t1.* from t1 join city c on t1.cityname=c.district
```

Comment: neat, I didn't think of joining cityname and district together. I got it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as:

```
SELECT country_name, city_name, continent
FROM (SELECT co.name as country_name, ci.name as city_name, co.continent, ci.district
      FROM country co INNER JOIN
           city ci
           ON co.code = ci.countrycode
      ORDER BY ci.population DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) cc
WHERE district = city_name;
```

In other words, you don't need an additional `JOIN`.  You can just select the columns you need in the subquery/CTE.

Comment: Cool I'll give this a try too